# WordPress z-index maybe

Tags: css, wordpress, z-index

[On this site](http://condo.icobb.com/) in the search in the header  I can't click the top two AJAX search results because I think they are under another layer. (Search for: condo). I have tried messing with the z-index. I changed the background color of the header to be able to see the top two search results. Here's what I put in the child CSS:

```
.fusion-sticky-header-wrapper {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
}

.fusion-header-v2 .fusion-header, .fusion-header-v3 .fusion-header,
.fusion-header-v4 .fusion-header, .fusion-header-v5 .fusion-header {
   display: block;
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}

.search-in-place, .item {
   z-index: 10000;
}
```

Same results with other plugins so I know it must be in the site CSS, right? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header bar is over the search results because of this declaration:

```
.fusion-header-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10010;
}
```

To solve this you would need to remove the z-index declaration from the header wrapper or set the z-index for the search results higher than 10010, for example:

```
.search-in-place, .item {
    z-index: 10020;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @harzzn, I actually didn't see the z-index for fusion-header-wrapper but I'm still at a loss why z-index 2 !important; didn't move it back to a lower z (not that I would have left it there. Either way, thanks for your help. Now there is yet another high level layer :/

Comment: @mrmunk yeah I'm afraid the only other option would be to remove the z-index declaration from the wrapper but not sure if this is currently possible for you to do? Nevertheless, could you mark the answer as correct if it solved the issue, thanks :)

Comment: If I remove the z-index from the theme and not through the child CSS, it will be over-written on update. But you already knew that. Thanks.